# Flutter | firebase_messaging :: onBackgroundMessage() won't work after Reboot on iOS

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

Also wrote a post on the firebase github with lot of infos they demand in order to be abl to post if it can helps here too :
https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/12324

Briefly :

- Our app is in Flutter
- Android part works 100% All the time :
  -- Notifs received 100% of the time
  -- Notifs are 100% BG handled whether the app is in foreground, background, killed/terminated state, and even after device reboot.
- iOS part "partly" works :
  -- Notifs received 100% of the time !
  -- Notifs are BG Handledwhen app is in foreground, background, and even if we kill/terminate the app after this by switching up the app in the recent apps list, notification are still received and BG handled.

## BUT AFTER THE IPHONE's REBOOT :

- The BG handling part is "broken...".
- We correctly receive the notification (sometimes with seconds of latency...)
- BUT the BG code is ignored !

and as we can see in the MacOs console stackTrace :

> response : { Decision : Must Not Proceed , Score : 0.00  [...]  }

What are we missing so that the BG part still works after the device's reboot on iOS !?
Did i miss a configuration part or something ? a parameter maybe ? (We do use content-available : true and priority ones)

Any help would be MUCH appreciated ! (^_^)

Thanks in advance.

EDIT :: Did more tests and described "diagnosis" with screenshots on the github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/12324
Please help ? :s

Comment: "Up" please ? :s

Answer (score 0):

You can have a check on the firebase documentation, when device is termianted in IOS platform, the onBackgroundMessage() will not be working properly.

1. Link to the GitHub discussion:
   https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/11500
2. Link to the firebase documentation:
   https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/flutter/receive

   (On iOS, if the user swipes away the application from the app switcher, it must be manually reopened for background messages to start working again.)

Comment: Indeed i saw this but some devs say they managed to !
And there are subjects on firebase's github suggesting it can work...

Like mentionned i did post my problem myself no one of the firebase Team to answer this won't work...

I think firebase should way better communicate on this very point it's too important for devs that this sould be 100% clear since the start :(